# WP 8.1 - How to save an image to Isolated Storage if know it's URL

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, isolatedstorage

I have the **image URL**.

How can I **save** it into *Isolated Storage* in WP 8.1.

Can I trigger both ***save*** it and then ***share*** it onto Facebook with only one button?

This is my code - which work well following Burak Kaan Köse's:

```
public async void GetImage()
    {
        StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            if (folder != null)
            {
                StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("imagefile", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                string url = imgUri[fLFl.SelectedIndex].ToString();
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                byte[] fileContent = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url); ; // This is where you set your content as byteArray

                Stream fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
                fileStream.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
                fileStream.Flush();
                fileStream.Dispose();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to change 'imagefile' path and fileContent variable.

```
private async void SaveFile()
{
    try
    {
        StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        if(folder != null)
        {
            StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("imagefile", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            byte[] fileContnet = null; // This is where you set your content as byteArray
            Stream fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
            fileStream.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
            fileStream.Flush();
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Some Exception handling code
    }
}
```

Comment: IsolatedStorageFile doesn't exist in WP 8.1 - so that i cant find the GetUserStoreForApplication() method.

Comment: Sorry my bad , didn't pay attention.Just modified my code.IsolatedStorage does not exists in Windows Phone 8.1 , it's replaced with ApplicationData instead to adapt the current system to more Windows Runtime approach.